# How can I recover encrypted data from a previous Ubuntu installation?

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, encryption, ecryptfs, data-recovery

I tried to upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 but it crashed. It couldn't mount disk drives so I did a new installation without erasing the previous drives. Now I can't access access-your-private-data.

Comment: I'm guessing by your tag that your old home folder was encrypted?  Just a tip, I know this is stressful, but if you want someone to help you with this you are going to need to be **a lot** more specific with what happened and what errors you are encountering.

Comment: Initially i was working on ubuntu 10.10, then i tried to upgrade to 11.04 throught update manager everything was until it installed all the packages. It stopped suddenly and i only had the option to use the power button and restart. And at the loader it said that the "disk drive for / is not ready or not present" Press S to skip memory test or M for manual recovery, Pressing "S" then gives the message but instead of disk drives it is tmp,manually, have to try the method described here http://goshawknest.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/how-to-recover-crypted-home-directory-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem, and discovered [ecryptfs-recover-private](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html) from Dustin Kirkland's blog. This utility interactively asks for your login password, which I have, and then mounted my old home directory in /tmp/ecrypt.hAsHeD and I am now able to copy out everything I need.

Answer (score 1):

From [@shapr's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/154802):

> I have this same problem, and discovered `ecryptfs-recover-private` from Dustin Kirkland's blog. This utility interactively asks for your login password, which I have, and then mounted my old home directory in `/tmp/ecrypt.hAsHeD`

I had to add the directory of my `/.Private` to make it works:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /home/.ecryptfs/david/davidgb/.Private
[sudo] Mot de passe de david : 
INFO: Found [/home/.ecryptfs/david/davidgb/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [83f90551aa14b856] into the user session keyring
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.Gko7hLsl].
```