# Restore Encrypted /home partition

Tags: ext4, data-recovery, ecryptfs

I need to recover my lost data.

Tonight I reinstalled ubuntu without formatting `/home`, thinking that ubuntu was enought smart to install itself without wiping the previous data in directory like Downloads and so on.

When the installation process started I use for the user name the same name of my previous account. The Home directory encryption option was uncheckable and so I installed with the encryption. Then the installation went wrong during the copy of the beginning files. I installed ubuntu again (in another partition) and now Ubuntu ran good but I cant't mount or enter my previous home directory with all the data in it.

I tried to mount it with `encrypt-recovery` but it just mounts the other directory empty.

Gparted however told me that the partition is full. I only have 50 GB on my `/home` partition and the partition has just 40 GB of free space. But if I navigate it with nautilus I can't see any of those files.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an answer here, and I have the same problem.  I saw another thread suggesting use of ecryptfs-recover-private (link below) and I'll be doing that soon.  If you want to recover the entire home, here is what I will be doing. Using the utility to open the .private; backup the contents unencrypted to a giant usb drive, also copy the .private folder there just out of paranoia.  Then, clear the partition and set as home.  Once it works, copy the contents back from the usb drive and reboot (with fingers crossed).
Here is that link:
[How can I recover encrypted data from a previous Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141510/how-can-i-recover-encrypted-data-from-a-previous-ubuntu-installation)

PS: Why not just do this and then post my experience and not just the plan?  It's going to take a while and once crisis passed I may forget!