# How to recover encrypted home data with Live CD?

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs

Last night I closed my computer and when I try to login to my account I get rejected even though my password is correct.  I tried to reset the PW but nothing so in second place I try to recover my data I put a live CD but when I try to access to my partition via live CD I have two files one named Access-Your-Private-Data and Readme.

I tried to recover my data with the ecryptfs method but I couldn't it give nothing same problem.

please help me because I have all my work there I didn't even encrypted my home I just found it that way.

P.S. I think that this problem was originally because I don't have any space left in my HD, and I have been getting a message that said that a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I should refer to this useful [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141510/how-can-i-recover-encrypted-data-from-a-previous-ubuntu-installation); I think what you're looking for is the [ecryptfs-recover-private](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html) utility.

Answer (score 0):

This is how:

- make sure that your target system's hard drive is mounted
- open a terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>
- type `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private` and press <kbd>enter</kbd> for it to run
- follow the prompts
- access your decrypted data and save somewhere else
- you can also launch the graphical file browser with `sudo nautilus` and navigate to the temporary directory

Source: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/04/introducing-ecryptfs-recover-private.html